# Toggle click() with same class names?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple toggle that's going to be applied to more than one section of my web application. However, I do not want to just change the class name and add another event to trigger it.

Can I use something like `parent()` or `nextUntil()` to achieve this? What is usually the best practice for this situation?

https://jsfiddle.net/smod3dvp/

Comment: No. Sorry I may not have explained well. I want to separate the events. So when click on details only that one specific .details shows under .information

Comment: You should be using `closest()`, not `parent()` or `parents()` -> https://jsfiddle.net/smod3dvp/3/

Comment: While they both work. What is the reason to use `closest()` instead?

Comment: `closest()` stops when it finds the first matching element, while `parents()` just keeps going all the way up to the `document` level, meaning it's highly inefficient and could match other elements with the same class higher up the DOM tree.

Comment: ah. OK that makes sense. Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

use parents to find common identifiable parent and then use find like

```
$(this).parents(".information").find(".details").fadeToggle("fast");
```

Comment: That did it! I was going crazy. I kept using parent() not parents().